# What SQL database permissions are required for the SignalR backplane?

Tags: signalr

I'm setting up a SQL backplane for SignalR. The documentation for setting up SignalR indicates that you need a user that has CREATE permissions on the database that will be used as the backplane.

I can't seem to find documentation on what those tables will be. I'd like to be able to give the DBA a script to create the tables. Barring that, is it safe to grant CREATE permissions long enough for SignalR to do what it needs, and then back them off to standard reader/write permissions?

**EDIT:** I'm aware of what the documentation recommends. As has been pointed out, the most commonly cited source is [this article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server). I'd like to get a better sense of what SignalR is going to be doing with the permissions that the article says are needed, and whether we can just provide the required schema and tables, or if there's more going on.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question that would lead to a downvote? I'd like to make it better. My research thus far as been inconclusive. There's a lot of information from SignalR 1.x, and very early versions of the backplane feature, but nothing that I'd call definitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR creates 3 tables,  you can not create these tables by you self as SignalR drops these tables and recreates them as needed.

If you are worried about giving SignalR Create premisions on your production DB
you can create a separated schema and give SignalR permissions only on that Schema.

Comment: Ok, the added tidbit is that SignalR creates *and* drops the tables according to it's own rules. The problem we were having wasn't that it was doing it, but knowing the full scope of what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: Would you please explain the schema approach a little more. how can I avoid giving the permission on the production server?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a script that creates a database, creates a user with a password of your choosing, and gives that user rights to your database. Let the application create and manage the schema (ie. tables) for you as described in the documentation.

Documentation: [SignalR Scaleout with SQL Server](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server)

> **Configure the Database**
>
> Decide whether the application will use Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication to access the database. Regardless, make sure the database user has **permissions to log in, create schemas, and create tables**.

Comment: How does this answer the question asked ? I do not want to give db owner permission to the prod user id. Why does signalR need to recreate db every time ?

Comment: @akjha627 - if you have a question about how to configure `SignalR` please ask it on a new question.